# Access folders in root directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am developing an asp.net web application. I have to access one of the image in images folder in root directory. I am using following code in my code behind file.

```
string imageDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/");
string imageUrl = imageDirectory + "/img1.bmp";
```

This works fine in my local machine. My question is does this code work when I move my application to production ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should as long as you have an application root/virtual directory for your site.

Also, you can combine these two lines into:

```
string imageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/img1.bmp");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking of putting `imageUrl` into an `<img>` tag, then no, it won't work. `Server.MapPath` will return your file or directory as a local Windows file/directory name, so something like "C:\WebRoot\MyWebApplication".  If you send this to the browser, obviously, the browser won't pick up the image.

What you can do is something like:

```
string imageUrl = ResolveClientUrl("~/images/myImage.gif");
```