# How do you get the root of the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, web-config, appsettings

Hi I am programming in C# and building a website. I am trying to use AppSettings in the web config to set paths to image folders so that I can use those AppSettings anywhere in the site to sort of use as a shortcut to the image folders. I can not figure out how to get the main root of the website so that I can just call this from any folder and get the right path.

Comment: You can resolve the root url like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077558/use-of-tilde-in-asp-net-path

Comment: post this as an answer this worked!! @TGH

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542610/access-folders-in-root-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also returns the root:

```
<img src="~/apps/thisapp/images/logo.gif" alt="" runat="server" />
```

Or

```
Server.MapPath("~")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get by   `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`